# The eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors for the matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&2&2\\
2&0&2\\
2&2&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have calculated the equation for eigenvalues, which is $\lambda^3-4\lambda-16=0$, but how do I solve this equation? Can this matrix be diagonalized?

Comment: Can you use MathJax to type out the matrix?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I've run GNU [Octave online](https://octave-online.net/) with `A = [0 2 2 ; 2 0 2; 2 2 0]; poly(A)` and get `1,0,-12,-16`, which shows that the characteristic polynomial is $t^3-12t-16=0$.  Solving this with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3-12x-16=0) gives eigenvalues $-2, 4$.  Can you find the eigenspace $\mathsf{N}(\lambda I - A)$ from this?

Comment: Apparantly, I am the only one to use PARI/GP. It approves that $-2$ and $4$ are the eigenvalues, $-2$ is double and that the matrix can be diagonalized via $$\pmatrix{-1&-1&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&1}$$

Comment: The downvote has no reason I can think of.  The question is clear, the OP showed what he/she did. If it is because of missing format : Why not just editing instead of downvoting ?

Comment: It is true that the characteristic polynomial is falsely calculated, but this does not justify a downvote either.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to remember that any real symmetric matrix can always be (orthogonally) diagonalized. This is an easy case of the much more general spectral theorem on normal operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have calculated the equation for eigenvalues, which is $\lambda^3-4\lambda-16=0$, but how do I solve this equation?

Your characteristic equation is wrong. You can avoid having to solve a cubic equation by first using some properties of determinants; e.g. subtracting the third column from the second and then adding the third row to the second:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda&2&2\\
2&-\lambda&2\\
2&2&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda&0&2\\
2&-\lambda-2&2\\
2&2+\lambda&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda&0&2\\
4&0&2-\lambda\\
2&2+\lambda&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$$
Expanding along the second column now gives:
$$(2+\lambda)\left(-\lambda(2-\lambda)-8\right)=0 \iff (2+\lambda)^2(\lambda-4)=0 \iff \lambda = -2 \vee \lambda = 4$$
Now proceed with finding the corresponding eigenvectors. You should find two linearly indepedent eigenvectors for the double eigenvalue $\lambda = -2$, so yes: the matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

One can quickly find the eigenvalues of a matrix of this form without forming and solving the characteristic equation. Call your matrix $A$. Observe that the matrix of all $2$’s is singular. That matrix is equal to $A+2I$, so $-2$ is an eigenvalue. It should be clear that the kernel of $A+2I$ is two-dimensional, so $-2$ is at least a double eigenvalue. Using the fact that the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues, we find that the third eigenvalue is $0-2(-2)=4$.

More generally, the same line of reasoning shows that the eigenvalues of the matrix $\small{\pmatrix{a&k&k\\k&a&k\\k&k&a}}$ are $a-k$, $a-k$ and $a+2k$. This has a straightforward generalization to $n\times n$ matrices as well.